# JavaScript function callable without onclick?

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I am new in a project and we are using thymeleaf combined with JavaScript.

I wrote functions which delivers the background color depending on the availability of the choosen element. I have to copy more or less the functionality of "th:disable" for a div, since this functionality is not available for a div. Unfortunately, my functions are never called, I assume the reason is because I have no onClick event or something, I want to call the function it the "th:styleappend".

```
<div th:styleappend="|background-color: getBackgroundColor(${element})|">


<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/gridstack-logic.js}"></script>
    <script th:inline="javascript">


function getBackgroundColor(element){
     console.log("##############in getBackgroundColor");
     if(kachel.bool1&& bool2){
         return rgba(153,168,177,0.05);
     }
     return "${element.backgroundcolor}";
}

</script>
```

I tried several things but none of them was working

Comment: Thymeleaf cannot call Javascript functions, it can only inject objects/JSON into JavaScript code.

Comment: when I put the method in "th:onclick" the method is called since I got the console log. Or got I something wrong?

Comment: Because in HTML `onclick` contains JavaScript but `style` contains CSS.

Comment: And is onclick the only possibility to trigger a JavaScript function? I was looking for other entrypoints but i found non

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the "onLoad" events in the next page:

[onLoad Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

```
<img src="w3javascript.gif" onload="loadImage()" width="100" height="132">

<script>
function loadImage() {
  alert("Image is loaded");
}
</script>
```

And also for the changes made on the webpage you could assign [onChange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event, on eahc of the items that you are trying to verify if changes.